# How to combine attributes/fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: sql, types, elasticsearch, field, associate

When designing an application I would like to know whether ElasticSearch is a suitable tool for implementing it (and how to do it). Any advice will be much appreciated!

My application needs to store (many) documents, each document being represented as a sequence of words. I want also to associate information with each word. For example, suppose I want to associate the word length with each word. So I would have something like this:

```
The      house   is      yellow
3        5       2       6
```

Now, I would like to perform queries such as for instance "give me words with length 2, followed by the word 'yellow'". In a relational database I would store the word forms and lengths as different attributes, for instance:

```
Word        Length        N
---------------------------
the           3           1
house         5           2
is            2           3
yellow        6           4
```

(where N is the position of the word) and in SQL I would make something like this:

```
SELECT word, N1 as N
FROM   documents
WHERE  (word=”yellow” AND N1 in (SELECT N2 as N
                                 FROM documents
                                 WHERE length=2 AND (N1-N2=1 OR N2-N1=1)
       )
)
```

I'm struggling to implement this same functionality into ElasticSearch. I've read online manuals and the reference book, but I'm unable to figure out how to do this with ES. So any advice from your part will be very much appreciated.

Take into account:
The database will have many attributes associated with words, and I'll need to query for any combination of them.
Those attributes are pre-computed and loaded into the database offline.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like this is something you could accomplish through a custom analyzer that wrote the length of the term into the "payload" of the term. You could then access the payload from a script to perform custom scoring/filtering.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for answering. I have read information and examples about custom analyzers but I still don't know how to do it.

This is the document mapping I have done:

```
        "mappings" : {
        "Sentence": {
            "properties" : {
                    "word":{
                        "type":"string",
                           "index" : "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "attributes":{
                           "properties":{
                                "length”: {
                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "index_analyzer": "standard"
                                },
                                "N": {
                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "index_analyzer": "standard" 
                                }
                           }
                     } 
            }
        }
   }
```

This is the indexed document:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/documents/Sentence/1 -d '
    {
    "Sentence":[                  
        {"word":"the",     
         "attributes":{          
            "length”:3,
            "N":1
         }
        },
        {"word":"house",
         "attributes":{
            "length”:5,
            "N":2
         }
        },
        {"word":"is",
         "attributes":{
            "length”:2,
            "N":3
         }
        },
        {"word":"yellow",
         "attributes":{
            "length”:6,
            "N":4
         }
        }
    ]
}';
```

I try to do execute the previous query ("give me words with length 2, followed by the word 'yellow'") using span queries:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/documents/Sentence/_search?pretty -d '
    {
        "query": {
           "span_near": {
                "clauses": [
                    {"span_term" : {"word":"yellow"}},
                    {"span_term" : {"length”:2}}
                ],
                "slop":0
            }
        }

}';
```

But I can't do that because clauses must have same field. So I have discard that option (span query).

How could I create the custom analyzer to execute the query I want?

Thank you.